# How to detach document windows from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++builder

I've got 2 displays with very different resolution (which makes just stretching a window over them not a good idea) and actively use both of them, usually looking at one when doing changes in another.

So I wonder if I could move a child window of Visual Studio 2010 from within the boundaries of it's main window an move it to another display. Nowadays I'd enjoy [the way child windows behaved (each window, incl a toolbar and a properties pane worked as an independent window on a desktop) in Borland C++ Builder](http://www.activexperts.com/xmstoolkit/howto/mm1rx/cppbuilder/fig01-sm.gif) (while it was senseless the days when I actually was using it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 Document Windows are (finally) detachable. For an how to, you can check this post:

[Free your Document windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/zainnab/archive/2010/01/15/free-your-document-windows.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zainnab+%28Visual+Studio+Tips+and+Tricks%29)

Basically there are different ways you can achieve this:

1. Simply click and drag the tab for the Document window out of the IDE;
2. Go to Window -> Float on the Menu Bar.